# How can i solve this error when installing tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\tensorboard_plugin_wit\_vendor\tensorflow_serving\sources\storage_path\**pycache**\file_system_storage_path_source_pb2.cpython-38.pyc'

Answer (score 0):

That is a rare error and it happens mostly if there is something wrong with your installation. I would recommend reinstalling python. However, here are a few things which may fix your issue. Furthermore, you have not provided enough info. How are you installing? I take it you are using pip.

1. Run your command line as admin.
2. Try using --user to have the installation take place in you home directory.
3. Follow that path one directory at a time and make sure the `.pyc` file is not in the wrong directory. If it is, move it to the correct one.
4. Use --upgrade and --force-reinstall to try and force the package to be downloaded again.

If any of these work, mention it here please so that others would know what worked.